# p2pool.util.jsonrpc.NarrowError: -10

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, p2pool

I'm attempting to run P2Pool locally on my other machine and getting this issue while running bitcoind:

```
2016-12-19 09:56:24.100000 p2pool (version unknown 7032706f6f6c2d7032706f6f6c2d39633662323130)
2016-12-19 09:56:24.100000
2016-12-19 09:56:24.100000 Testing bitcoind RPC connection to 'http://127.0.0.1:8332/' with username 'bitcoinrpc'...
Error getting work from bitcoind:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 651, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1355, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\bitcoin\p2pool-p2pool-9c6b210\p2pool\util\deferral.py", line 41, in f
    result = yield func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "C:\bitcoin\p2pool-p2pool-9c6b210\p2pool\bitcoin\helper.py", line 53, in getwork
    work = yield go()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "C:\bitcoin\p2pool-p2pool-9c6b210\p2pool\util\jsonrpc.py", line 133, in _http_do
    raise Error_for_code(resp['error']['code'])(resp['error']['message'], resp['error'].get('data', None))
p2pool.util.jsonrpc.NarrowError: -10 Bitcoin is downloading blocks...
```

I know the last line indicates that the bitcoin block is still downloading but the bitcoin core gui indicates that I am up to date. I've tried shutting down the bitcoin client and restarting a couple of times with no luck.

I have no idea if I'm missing something obvious here or not.

Comment: If you run getblockcount on the Bitcoin GUI, what do you get? Is it the same as on blockexplorer?

Comment: @NickODell 444200 and yup it's the same on the site.

Answer (score 2):

So I found the reason behind the block downloading issue.

I had forgot to point to the block's data dir when running bitcoind. So instead of utilizing the block downloaded from the GUI it was downloading an entirely new block and using that one instead.